# How should I reply appropriately if my boss tells me that they are sick in an e-mail?

Tags: germany, sickness, culture

How should I reply appropriately if my boss tells me that they are sick in an e-mail (the e-mail was sent only to me)? Would "I hope you will get better soon" be enough? Or should I also say something along the line of "I feel bad for you"?

Answers from any cultural contexts are welcome. (I am from Germany.)

Comment: Email to just you, or a group? If it was to a group, I wouldn't respond unless it appeared to be a serious illness. Does your boss really need his email clogged up with "get well soon" emails?

Comment: German, too. What is the context if you call in sick? My boss emails me: "Ok, thanks for the note. Get well soon."  - I my boss would call in sick to me, I'd reply just the same, then forward the information to my teams secretary of to whom it may concern.

Comment: I assume "sick" means "I have influenza and am out today" and not something like "I have cancer" in this context (as those would be very, very different things)?

Comment: @Mattman944 if everyone takes that attitude, then the boss gets no "get well soon" email at all. If it's a group email, I'd respond if nobody else already has and if others have, but there's pertinent questions boss needs to answer for something I'm working on, then make it part of my normal email.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Don't overthink it. "Feel better soon!" is fine. You can also clarify if there's anything special your boss needs you to handle while they are recovering. This is what I usually reply to emails like that,

> Sorry to hear that, I hope you feel better soon. Let me know if there's anything I can handle for you here in the office while you're out.

Answer (score 29):

Just don't make it weird.

Ask if there is anything you can do while they are off work, and leave the "get better soon" last like an email signature.

Comment: Dear boss, On the advice of Hristo Kolev as per https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/152036/114003 I am not going to make this weird and instead wish you to get better soon. Sincerely, Aqqqq

Comment: @corsiKa: you forgot the xoxoxo and a picture of an inappropriate cake.

Answer (score 17):

A very simple message will do. Don't "make it weird" like Hristo Kolev said. Something like...

> Hello Boss,
>
> I am sorry to hear about your sickness. Let me know if there's
>   anything I can do for you.
>
> Feel better soon!
>
> Thanks, Aqqq

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica I think the example, while not giving new content from the previous answer, adds something to it. Explaining is good, showing is better.

Answer (score 7):

Context: Canadian tech company

If the email is to me, and me alone, I would respond with:

> Ok, thanks for telling me.

or, if I think they will need me to do something while they are sick:

> Ok, do you need me to cover anything while you are out?

If the email is to a group, like the department or company, I wouldn't respond at all. The email has done it's job, there is no need to further complicate matters with needless communication.

"Get well soon" and similar platitudes are just meaningless small talk. Save that for when the boss comes back to work.

Comment: I agree "Get well soon" is often just a platitude, but omitting expected platitudes can come off wrong way, *especially* in written communication. To me "Ok, thanks for telling me." kind of sounds like you couldn't care less that the other person is sick.

Comment: It all depends on what relationship you have with your boss.

Comment: platitudes and politeness are absolutely required, especially in many european countries.  I don't like small talk but I accept it is required by others in my societies in order to make things work better for all.  Given the choice I'd likely never use small talk, however the resulting effect on me from others would be deleterious.   So I follow my society conventions as needed.  I'm individual in many other ways I can show.

Comment: @kapex Assuming this is my boss and not my close personal friend, not being able to care less is pretty close to accurate. This is a professional business relationship, not an after-school club. My boss matters to me to the extent that they give me work and I give them results. If I am friendly with my boss I'll absolutely sympathize with them at the water cooler when they get back, but that doesn't have any place in an official work email.

Comment: +1 but presumably by the time the boss comes back to work, he/she's already "gotten well", and "get well soon" is too late.

Comment: I'm not sure why the "Canadian tech company" is specified since, as other users are saying, "Ok, thanks for telling me" would be weird and off-putting at any tech company I've worked at, both Canadian and American.  "Get well soon" indicates that you are a human being, not that you are personally friendly with your boss.  An official work email is not the place to jump at the chance to make a point of how you don't care, either, indirectly or not.

Comment: @MatthewRead The context is specified because the OP specified their context and also opened it up to other contexts. The approach is specified because it is the approach I currently use at the specified context, and it works well, and other people should do the same thing.
This is not hard to understand.

Answer (score -4):

I respond ":(" in such situations. My boss sometimes mentions it (in a group) as something a bit silly, but funny and nice.

Comment: This is probably not appropriate in most cases. Really depends what kind of relationship you have with your boss. Given each relationship is unique, I don't think offering this advise is helpful.

Comment: Also, If you incorporate some of @ChickenFeet's comments into your answer, it might be better received.